# EmberJS - didInsertElement em novos elementos

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma lista de tópicos que recebe o evento popover do bootstrap no carregamento da página.

Mas quando eu adiciono novos tópicos a essa lista sem recarregar a página eu não consigo fazer o bind do popover no novo tópico.

Meu codigo atualmente está organizado da seguinte maneira:

Forum route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      run: this.store.find('run', this.modelFor('dialogo.admin.manager').get('id')),
      topics: this.store.find('topic', { run: this.modelFor('dialogo.admin.manager').get('id') })
    });
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('runID', this.modelFor('dialogo.admin.manager').get('id'));
    controller.set('model', model.topics);
    controller.set('currentRun', model.run);
  }
});
```

Forum Controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  activeUser: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.model"),
  actions: {
    createTopic: function() {
      var
        store = this.get('store'),
        user = this.get('activeUser'),
        run = this.get('currentRun'),
        topic;

      topic = store.createRecord('topic', {
        content: '',
        run: run,
        moderator: user
      });

      this.set('newTopic', topic);
    },
    saveNewTopic: function() {
      var newTopic = this.get('newTopic');
      var topicList = this.get('model');

      newTopic.save().then(function(topic){
        topicList.pushObject(topic);
        Ember.$('#newTopic').modal('hide');
      });
    },
    deleteTopic: function (topic) {
      topic.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```

Forum View:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      html : true,
      content: function() {
        var delID = Ember.$(this).attr('data-del');
        return Ember.$('#alertDel' + delID).html();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Forum Template:

```
  <tbody>
    {{#each topic in model}}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{topic.id}}</th>
        <td>{{topic.content}}</td>
        <td>{{topic.posts.length}}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="focus" data-del="{{topic.id}}" title="ATENÇÃO: Deletar tópico">
            DEL
          </button> |
          <span>EDIT</span> |
          <span>PEND</span> |
          <span>MOD</span>
          <div id="alertDel{{topic.id}}" style="display: none;">
            Você deseja deletar o tópico #ID {{topic.id}}?
            Essa ação não poderá ser desfeita.
            <br><br>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" {{action 'deleteTopic' topic}}>Sim</button> |
            <button class="btn btn-default">Não</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{else}}
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">Nenhum tópico encontrado...</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

Então quando eu executo a função saveNewTopic e adiciono um novo tópico a lista "topicList", perco meu evento popover.

Procurei bastante sobre isso mas não encontrei uma solução...

Alquém tem alguma pista de como poderia fazer o bind do evento popover nas novas instâncias de tópico?

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Pra serve a mensagem em ingles "Anyone have a clue about how can I bind my popover event on new topic instances?" na pergunta? Somos uma comunidade de Q&A em portugues.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento foi erro meu na hora de traduzir minha mensagem. Desculpe... Já corrigi removendo a frase em inglês.

Comment: Já experimentou com event-delegation ? (passei para comentário porque aquilo __não__ era uma resposta) (nao precisa de voltar a responder)